# Math typesetting bug when a question is closed

Tags: bug, status-completed

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22815/pi-4-how-to-disprove

I have noticed this before as well. When a question is marked duplicate and  closed, the possible duplicate question appears at the beginning of the post but there is a math typesetting error when it inserts the duplicate link at the beginning of the post. (Theo Buehler and Artuto did the edit for it to appear properly but I undid it so that the bug can be seen)

The same problem occurs for this question as well https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37630/how-to-express-log-p-q-if-log-p-4-m-and-log-sqrt2-q-n

Another evidence of this bug

[Is the $\sum\sin(n)/n$ convergent or divergent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36732/is-the-sum-of-sinn-n-convergent-or-divergent/36734#36734)

I reported this on the meta of math.stackexchange as well but no action was taken.

[Math typesetting bug when a question is closed](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1677/math-typesetting-bug-when-a-question-is-closed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, on MathJax enabled sites we won't escape `\` in titles moved to the post body if the title contains a `$`.

There are some other possible edge conditions but this fix should suffice for now.